# Python with dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

So i want to have a text like:
`pretty = [beautiful, attractive, good-looking]`

And in python i have an input from the user.

`UserInput= input()`

I want to check if the UserInput matches any word inside the list. If there is a match i want to replace the word that matched with "Pretty".

I tried this.

```
userInput = input()
userInput.split()
for word in userInput:
   if word in pretty:
      userInput.replace(word,"pretty")
```

This does not do anything. It does not replace the matching word.

One more question if i have multiple lists and want to check through all of them. What would be the best way?

Answer (score 1):

`.split()` and `.replace()` is not an in-place method like `.sort()` on list because strings are immutable object in python unlike list which are mutable object in python. While looping, you need to split, not before that. Also, you need to reassign `userInput` to the new string with `word` being replaced by some other sub-string.

Try this :

```
userInput = input()
for word in userInput.split():
   if word in pretty:
      userInput = userInput.replace(word,"pretty")
```

Comment: @Mike5732 Depends on your requirement. You can merge lists to create one mother list and check with the merged list or you can iterate through all of those lists separately. Better would be to merge and use the merged list.

Answer (score 0):

You have to store userInput.split() to a variable. .split() returns a list but won't directly update userInput. As it is now your, loop will go through each character in userInput and not words.

So try this

```py
userInput = userInput.split()
```

You have to reassign the userInput variable when you find a match. But before you do that you have to convert the list back to a string

```py
userInput = " ".join(userInput).replace(word, "pretty")
```

This works for me

```py
pretty = ["beautiful", "attractive", "good-looking"]

userInput = input()
userInput = userInput.split()
for word in userInput:
    if word in pretty:
        userInput = " ".join(userInput).replace(word, "pretty")

print(userInput)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple with `enumerate`

```
pretty = ['beautiful', 'attractive', 'good-looking']

userInput = input("Enter the word :")
for i, word in enumerate(pretty):
    if userInput == word:
        pretty[i] = 'pretty'

print(pretty)
```

Test:

```
Enter the word :attractive
['beautiful', 'pretty', 'good-looking']
```

Comment: @Mike5732 That depends on the number of lists and the length of the lists (equal or unequal) as well. `zip` can be used for two lists or `itertools` if many lists.